# Cannot copy letters with diacritics from pdflatex PDF

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste

I have problem with copying text from PDF file.

I am using these packages in my document:

```
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

However when I generate PDF file, it doesn't allow me to copy slovak characters. For example copying this

```
nemožné k nim pristupovať
```

results in

```
nemoºné k nim pristupova´
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Which text editor do you use? And, is it capable of displaying utf8-encoded glyphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding package `lmodern` solved my problem:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Answer (score 2):

With reference to page 7 in the [MinioPro-manual](http://ctan.uib.no/fonts/minionpro/MinionPro.pdf), to make figures and ligatures searchable, you need to enable `glyphtounicode` translation and load the default mapping table:

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

`glyphtounicode` was included in my [MikTeX-](http://www.miktex.org)distribution, but if it is not included in yours, you can find it at [Sarovar](http://pdftex.sarovar.org/misc/).